# Jordan measurability of compact Half-space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A half-space in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is of the form,$$\left\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^d:x\cdot v\leq c\text{ where, }v\in\mathbb{R}^d,c\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$ how to prove  a compact half space is Jordan measurable.It seems to me for $d=2$ case it is just a rotated rectangle{ a rectangle whose sides may not be parallel to coordinate axis} and hence Joran measurable, then what about the general case i.e $n>2$?
it seems to me for the general case a compact half-space can be represented as the area under the graph of a continuous function with a compact domain, hence it is Jordan measurable. Am I right?

Comment: Your set is unbounded. In particular, not Jordan measurable.

Comment: sorry, I have forgotten to mention the word "compact".now I have edited the question.

Comment: What is a "compact half-space"? According to the definition you have given, no half-space is compact.

Comment: a compact half-space is a half-space which is bounded. that is the intersection of  the half-space with the set {x:||x||<=M},for some M>0